# Run NodeJS app in azure via container web app or normal web app in production

Tags: node.js, azure, containers, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

What's the best way to run a nodeJS application in production on Azure?
Using PM2 inside the docker image is no option here as it results in two layers of load balancing and monitoring thus more complexity.

**Options:**
**Use normal web app**

Pro:

- Can use PM2
- The application can use more than one process thus more    than one
  core per AppService Instance thus one AppServicePlan    Instance can
  be better used to capacity.

**Use container web app**

Pro:

- The application can easily be used somewhere else because of the
  docker image Better control over the environment

Cons:

- Only one process per AppServicePlan Instance
- Possible downtime if application crashes till the new container is
  ready

Answer (score 0):

Either of these options is completely valid. Your approach of weighing the pros and cons of each option is the correct one- these are going to be somewhat unique to your situation, which is why it is not possible to provide an overall "best" way to deploy an app.

One thing I will note is that Azure offers load balancing with [apps scaled out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json) to multiple instances, either manually or through rules that you set up. That would help mitigate downtime if an individual instance goes down.

[image]